# Inform class that action has happened - JAVA

Tags: java, callback, action

I would like to know how can I inform a specific class that action has happened? I heard there is something called "callbacks" but I didn't understand how exactly I can use it.

Comment: Please read on listener and handlers in java.

Comment: Look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html)

Comment: How you use them depends on the action you are trying to listen to.  It is a design pattern rather than a general solution which works the same in all cases.

Comment: This class of problem is usually solved using the "Observer" design pattern, which is straightforward to implement in Java and most other OO languages.

Answer (score 0):

Like the people above commented on you're post, you can do that with listener interfaces or with adapters that implement the required interface.

For example:

You have a JButton (called button) on the JFrame, you can click the button but nothing really happens.
What you will need to do is add the functionality, this can be done by adding a listener to the button, but first u need to create the listener!

The created listener:

```
public class TestClickedListener extends MouseAdapter {

  //The button text will be set to: Clicked!
  public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent source) {
    JButton buttonSource = (JButton)source.getSource();
    buttonSource.setText("Clicked!");
  }
}
```

In the main method of the JFrame u can then add the created MouseListener to the button:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
  button.addMouseListener(new TestClickedListener());
}
```

Now try and click the button ;)

I hope this wil help you out buddy, just a simple example to understand it :) !